# not able to execute command using "exec" in PHP (Could not open input parameters file)

Tags: php, shell, exec

I am executing blow command through my php file but getting an error. Please guide me what I am doing wrong.

```
exec('/var/www/sizeme/demo/imaguRunner /var/www/sizeme/demo/example/
parameters.txt',$output,$return_val);

Error
-----------------
Array ( [0] => FATAL: Could not open input parameters file "/var/www/sizeme/demo/example/parameters.txt". (from ImaguSeg_InitFromFile() at ../RunIt.cpp::170)
        [1] => FATAL: Could not open input parameters file "/var/www/sizeme/demo/example/parameters.txt". (from ImaguSeg_InitFromFile() at ../RunIt.cpp::170) )
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay.. got solution,

I need to change dir first and then executed command. see below code.

```
chdir('/var/www/sizeme/demo');
exec('/var/www/sizeme/demo/imaguRunner /var/www/sizeme/demo/example/
parameters.txt',$output,$return_val);
```

Thank God.